# How to wait for options of a select element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I want to select the option in the select element after all the options are drawn using a map method. I don't want to use setTimeout to wait for a while. I want to know after all the options are rendered.

The select is in a pop up modal which is shown after a button is clicked.

```
<select
    ref={classSelRef}
    className="form-select  mr-sm-2"
    id="class"
    required
    onChange={e => setClassId(e.target.value)}>
    {classes.map(c => {
        return (
            <option key={c.id} value={c.id}>
                {c.class_name}
            </option>
        )
    })}
</select>
```

And here is the option selection method.

```
const selectOption = (ele, value) => {
  return [...ele.options].some((option, index) => {
      if (option.value === value) {
          ele.selectedIndex = index
          return true
      }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add logical operator `&&` before map function like so

```
<select
ref={classSelRef}
className="form-select  mr-sm-2"
id="class"
required
onChange={e => setClassId(e.target.value)}>
{classes && classes.map(c => {
    return (
        <option key={c.id} value={c.id}>
            {c.class_name}
        </option>
    )
})}
```

---

This will wait `classes` to be `true` before map is executed